# Is host web always a site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

For a SharePoint hosted application, is the host web always referred to as a site collection, and it cannot be a web only ?

Let's assume I install a SharePoint hosted application at this address - which is a sub-sub web,

> site collection - http://www.studentportal.com/sites/classroom2
>
> http://www.studentportal.com/sites/classroom2/subject1

So is site collection host web or sub-sub-web is host web...

Comment: what you mean by Host web? are you asking about the App perspective?

Comment: In SharePoint applications we have hostweb and appweb.. so yes you are right, answer below has no authentic reference

Answer (score -1):

In regards to apps, Host web always refers to [the site that the app is installed on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179925(v=office.15).aspx).  In your proposed situation, the [token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163816(v=office.15).aspx) `{HostUrl}` would resolve to the latter: `http://www.studentportal.com/sites/classroom2/subject1`.